# If $X= \int_0^X dt$, why is it that: $X^a= a \int_0^X t^{a-1} dt$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, indefinite-integrals

I'm solving some problems in measure and integration theory, and found this result I cannot explain from my basic understanding:

If $X= \int_0^X dt$, then, $X^a= a \int_0^X  t^{a-1} dt$

Can somebody please explain to me what am I missing?.

The 'if' part is straight forward, but cannot explain the derivative of $X^a$ that shows up in the 'then' part.

Thanks folks.

Comment: Have you tried actually integrating $a \int^{X}_0 t^{a-1} dt$?

Comment: Yeah. I think I was just confused. Just realized that we are integrating the derivative of $X^a$, so then It makes sense..